# Getting value from Textview

Tags: android, android-activity, textview

How do I get a value from `TextView` and store it in a `String`? Here I am trying to create a string which has the TextView`s value and writing it into a file.

The code below is showing a run time error:

```
package com.ralley.par2;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Par2Activity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            TextView txtData1;

            txtData1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtData1);

            try {
            File myFile = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile.txt");

                myFile.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
                                        new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                String s = txtData1.getText().toString();
                myOutWriter.write(s);
                myOutWriter.close();
                fOut.close();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Done writing SD 'mysdfile.txt'",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } 


            catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Logcat Error:**

```
12-06 16:51:47.794: D/AndroidRuntime(3291): Shutting down VM
12-06 16:51:47.794: W/dalvikvm(3291): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
12-06 16:51:47.814: E/AndroidRuntime(3291): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 16:51:47.814: E/AndroidRuntime(3291): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ralley.par2/com.ralley.par2.Par2Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 16:51:47.814: E/AndroidRuntime(3291):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
12-06 16:51:47.814: E/AndroidRuntime(3291):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
12-06 16:51:47.814: E/AndroidRuntime(3291):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-06 16:51:47.814: E/AndroidRuntime(3291):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
12-06 16:51:47.814: E/AndroidRuntime(3291):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-06 16:51:47.814: E/AndroidRuntime(3291):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-06 16:51:47.814: E/AndroidRuntime(3291):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-06 16:51:47.814: E/AndroidRuntime(3291):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 16:51:47.814: E/AndroidRuntime(3291):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-06 16:51:47.814: E/AndroidRuntime(3291):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-06 16:51:47.814: E/AndroidRuntime(3291):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-06 16:51:47.814: E/AndroidRuntime(3291):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-06 16:51:47.814: E/AndroidRuntime(3291): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 16:51:47.814: E/AndroidRuntime(3291):     at com.ralley.par2.Par2Activity.onCreate(Par2Activity.java:30)
12-06 16:51:47.814: E/AndroidRuntime(3291):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-06 16:51:47.814: E/AndroidRuntime(3291):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
12-06 16:51:47.814: E/AndroidRuntime(3291):     ... 11 more
12-06 16:52:04.874: I/Process(3291): Sending signal. PID: 3291 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Textview needs to be initialized. For e.g. TextView txtData1 = new TextView(this);  OR TextView txtData1 = (TextView)findViewByID(R.id.yourtextview);

Comment: hi avinazz I have edited the question now.. pls have a look.

Comment: please paste your logcat.

Comment: Hi Dhruv.. I have pasted the complete code and errors. pls have a look..

Comment: You are missing the setContentView(); Nothing is available unless you do setContentView(R.layout.view);

Comment: Yes shoshi.. I did exactly the same.. I gace the ID in main.xml as 'txtData1`.

Comment: @Ashwin : ok that's right. and i am sorry cause i have removed my comment. Because, i thought ρяσѕρєя_K's given answer will solve your problem.

Comment: Thankyou avinaz.. but I need to know how we can set Visibility of main layout in the xml file..

Comment: android:visibility="gone" and from code mylayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Answer (score 5):

Currently you are not setting layout for Activity before getting UI elements from Current Activity layout so use `setContentView`  for setting layout for Activity as :

```
 public class Par2Activity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main); ///<<<<<<<Set layout here for Activity
           //....your code here....
```

Comment: I dont want any UI for the user.. so I have not set the main layout. I need it like when we run the application the textview`s value automatically copied into the file..

Comment: @Ashwin : what is your goal actually ??

Comment: @Ashwin : as you are saying *I need it like when we run the application the textview`s value automatically copied into the file.* when textview not exist in current View then how you can access it and save TextView value in file

Comment: You still have to inflate the view, but keep setVisibility to "GONE", in your xml or from code.

Comment: @prosper Sorry If I am doing something wrong. But Tell me is there any way we can do the same without displaying UI to the user?

Comment: @Ashwin : can u tell me what exactly you want .

Comment: Okay.We are working on one project where we run an application it takes some status from the phone and storing it in TextView. So I need to take that value from the TextView and write into a file. I am using String to store the TextView`s value. (The whole process runs in backround so I dont want and UI).

Comment: @Ashwin : if there is no view, there cannot be any TextView. if you try to retrieve text from a TextView, then you must have to provide a layout which will be set by `setContentView()` from an Activity.

Comment: @Ashwin : then why u are storing  status from the phone in TextView you can use SharedPreferences for storing value instead of TextView

Comment: if the user wants to see the .xml file, they have the option for it bro.

Comment: @Ashwin : when you are storing phone status in TextView, are you doing that it in another Activity? if yes, are you successful to show the data in the TextView ?

Comment: Yes shoshi.. That`s we have successfully did. And the user can see the status which is running in the backround just to know whats happening with the application.. By Default everything should run in the backround

Comment: @Ashwin : OK, then i guess you are starting `Par2Activity` activity from the previous activity (where u have successfully showing the status of the phone). if it is right, then you can put the status in an `Intent` and start the `Par2Activity` activty with the intent. and in `OnCreate()` method of `Par2Activity` retrieve the phone status from the intent with the help of `getStringExtra()` method. after that you can write the retrieved string.